# GLSL compile error '/' does not operate on 'vec4' and 'vec2'

Tags: glsl

Part of my fragment shader not compiling

```
vec2 uv=gl_FragCoord/uTDOutputInfo.res.zw;
```

returns the following error

> '/' does not operate on 'vec4' and 'vec2'

Also tried which gives same error.

```
vec2 uv=gl_FragCoord/iResolution.xy;
```

Comment: The type of [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) is `vec4`:  `vec2 uv=gl_FragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;`

Comment: Yep thanks! gl_FragCoord.xy works

Answer (score 3):

The type of [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) is `vec4`.
It is not possible to divide a vector with 4 components by a vector with 2 components.

Use [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) to get the x and y component of  `gl_FragCoord`:

```c
vec2 uv=gl_FragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
```